# .NET MVC 4 ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges() not saving all data correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple MVC application that allows CRUD operations on a Student-Course data base. I have a Student Model and a Course Model where Course.EnrolledStudents is a List. Now I have everything working to Add and Remove a Student to and from a course, however I am having trouble with one thing.

If I have a Student, "Joe Smith", and add him to class CS 101, then I attempt to also add him to CS 102, both Courses will show Joe Smith in the EnrolledStudents List UNTIL Db.SaveChanges() is called. Once that is called, the previous entry of Joe Smith in CS 101 gets removed and results in Joe Smith only being a part of the CS 102 course.

My guess is that it has to do with the database key values. In both instances, Joe Smith Student object has an key ID = 3, which makes me think that when the second entry is created, it sees that there is already a record with ID = 3 and it removes the old one.  Does this sound correct? If so, what can I do to stop it. Here is the relavent code:

**Roster Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Add(int courseId, int studentId)
        {
            Student newstudent = Db.Students.Find(studentId);
            //List<Course> courses = Db.Courses.ToList();
            Course course = Db.Courses.Find(courseId);
            course.EnrolledStudents.Add(newstudent);

            Db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = courseId });
        }

        public ActionResult Remove(int courseId, int studentId)
        {
            Course c = Db.Courses.Find(courseId);
            Student s = Db.Students.Find(studentId);

            c.EnrolledStudents.Remove(s);
            Db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = courseId});
        }
```

**Course Model**

```
public class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.EnrolledStudents = new List<Student>();
            CourseName = "Unknown";
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Student> EnrolledStudents {get; set;}
    }
```

**Student Model**

```
 public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `Id` and `StudentId` in your Student model?

Comment: Because `Id` is a database key Id where `StudentId` is like the personal Id number of a student at a university

Comment: On an unrelated note, consider using `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.  The former allows you to substitute in any implementation (what if later you need business logic, logging, performance enhancements, etc.)  The latter always ties you to that exact implementation.  Moreover, EF will substitute in ObservableCollection<T> (allowing it to efficiently detect modifications) when your relationships are typed as `ICollection<T>`, so consider using that if you don't actually care about accessing related entities by index.

Answer (score 2):

["By convention, Code First always interprets a unidirectional relationship as one-to-many."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#UniDirectional).  In your case, you have a uni-directional relationship from `Course` to `Students` via `EnrolledStudents`.  Since by convention the relationship is one-to-many (with "one" being `Course` and "many" being `Student`), each `Student` has only one course.  This is probably represented in the database by a column inside the Student table "CourseId".  I.e., there is only a single place to store the Course for a Student, so setting it twice overwrites.

If you want to have a many-to-many relationship, you can add a collection relationship from `Student` to `Course` or you can use the Entity Framework [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#ManyToMany) to override EF's convention.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(t => t.EnrolledCourses)
            .WithMany(t => t.EnrolledStudents);
    }
```

Comment: Your solution sounds correct, however after I added a `List<Course> enrolledCourses` into the Student Class, it did not change the outcome. Of course, I changed the Controller logic to add and remove from the List<Course> as needed

Comment: It would be worth updating the post with what the DB schema looks like for these entities.

Comment: You do not need to change your controller logic as far as Entity Framework is concerned.  Entity Framework detects the addition of the Student to the Course, and when you call SaveChanges, it uses the appropriate conventions to update the relationship in the DB.  In this case, you should have a table StudentCourses and EF would add a record to it pointing to both the student and the course(s).

Comment: For me, adding the relationship Student.Courses to your code created the StudentCourses table and allowed a Student to be in multiple courses.

Comment: I added an example of the Fluent API.  Try that and it really should create a many-to-many.